# BluetoothSocket.Connect Timeout

Tags: bluetooth, xamarin.android

I'm pulling my hair out on this one. I've searched all over the web for a working example, and haven't been able to find one.

I'm trying to connect to a Bluetooth device. The original code works in the Java version.

Everything works until Connect() is called, then everything just hangs. I need to be able to send and receive data to the bluetooth device, and my understanding is that Connect() must be called first.

Code:

```
// first, check that blue tooth is available
using (BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter)
{
    // if no adapter, then exit
    if (btAdapter == null)
    {
    // show toast message
    Toast.MakeText(m_Context, "Bluetooth is not turned on", ToastLength.Long).Show();

    // exit
    return false;
    }

    // we found an adapter, now get the list of attached devices
    foreach (BluetoothDevice device in btAdapter.BondedDevices)
    {
    // skip if not a P25
    if (!device.Name.ToLower().Contains("p25"))
        continue;

    BluetoothDevice mdevice = btAdapter.GetRemoteDevice(device.Address);

    IntPtr createRfcommSocket = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(
            mdevice.Class.Handle,
            "createRfcommSocket",
            "(I)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket;");
    IntPtr socket = JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(
        mdevice.Handle,
        createRfcommSocket,
        new JValue(1));

    // we found the device, confirm it's actually paired and turned on
    using (BluetoothSocket NewSocket = new Java.Lang.Object(socket).JavaCast<BluetoothSocket>())
    {
        try
        {
        // skip if nothing created
        if (NewSocket == null)
            continue;

        // connect
        NewSocket.Connect();

        // get the output stream
        NewSocket.OutputStream.Close();

        // close the socket
        NewSocket.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception excep)
        {
        Log.Error("DeviceLink", excep.Message);
        continue;
        }
    }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy, sorry my bad English, I believe you develop that to use with BlueBamboo, I have many problems too to print in Bluebamboo PM25 with Monodroid, solved like this, create a new class with 3 globals:

```
            public BluetoothAdapter Adapter;
            public BluetoothDevice RemoteDevice;
            public BluetoothSocket Socket;
```

Now in construtor of class

```
            Adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;

            if (Adapter == null) throw new NotSupportedException("Dispositivo sem suporte a bluetooth");
            if (!Adapter.IsEnabled) Adapter.Enable();

            foreach (var device in Adapter.BondedDevices)
            {
                if (!device.Name.ToLower().Contains("p25")) continue;

                RemoteDevice = Adapter.GetRemoteDevice(device.Address);
                Socket = RemoteDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

                if (Socket == null) continue;

                Socket.Connect();
                break;


            }
```

Instance only time this class in your Activity, after use, only close the SOCKET or implements IDisposable in your class.

```
         public void Dispose()
         {
              Socket.Close();
         }
```

Be happy!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old and I got here searching for something else but I was experiencing this same issue, to solve the 'hang' issue for me was running the connect portion on a different thread than the UI thread and then update the UI thread with the results. This is what is working for me..(BTW im using Monodroid for C#)

```
 private void connectBTwThread()
    {
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            TextView txtList = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.devicesList);

            #region Connect routine

            BluetoothSocket btSockets = bth.BondedDevices.Where(d => d.Name.ToUpper().Contains("JVC")).Single()
                .CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(_uuid);

            try
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    txtList.Text += System.Environment.NewLine;
                    txtList.Text += "Attempting to Connect to " + btSockets.RemoteDevice.Name
                        + System.Environment.NewLine;
                });

                btSockets.Connect();

                if (btSockets.IsConnected)
                    RunOnUiThread(() => { txtList.Text += "Connected to " + btSockets.RemoteDevice.Name; });

                btSockets.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() => { txtList.Text += "BT Connect Failed: " + e.Message + System.Environment.NewLine; });
                try
                {
                    btSockets.Close();
                }
                catch (IOException closeException)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            #endregion

        })).Start();
    }
```

I post it to give back to SO community and hopefully someone will benefit from this...